# Better way of directly accessing JSON child object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, loops, object

I have a fairly large JSON response structured similarly to this:

```
{
    "parent": [
        {
            "id": 1000,
            "name": "Example",
            "child": [
                {
                    "id": 2000,
                    "name": "Example"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to access `child`'s data where I know both the `parent` and `child's` `id`.  Seems like overkill to loop through both.  Ideally I can access the data something ***like***:

```
parent[id:1000].child[id:2000];
```

How can I access the child object without looping through all the parent and child objects?

Also, I designed this JSON object, and welcome any recommendations for improvements to it's structure given what I'm trying to accomplish.

The closest solution I've had is as follows, but seems like bad form:

```
{
    1000: [
        {
            "name": "Parent",
            2000: [
                {
                    "name": "Child"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: a number cannot be a key in json object. I would use the Array.prototype.filter method. Possibly creating a generic function to filter by id (would be trivial and short in coffee script a little more verbose in JS)

Comment: your last solution is OK, except you need to convert numbers to string: ie { "1000": { "name": "parent", "2000": { "name": "child" }, "2001":{ "name": "child+1" }// so on

Comment: jquery grep? https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Comment: A rare good question about JSON!

Comment: @AlexanderM Yeah just "OK" right? got your note about numbers to strings. Thanks.

Comment: @ggwarpig Actually lot of people will say that it is pure JavaScript way.

Answer (score 1):

A filter could be :

```
parent.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id == 1000
})[0].child.filter(function(item) {
    return item.id == 2000
})[0]
```

You can also define a function to filter by id:

```
byId = function(id) { return function(item) { return item.id == id} }
```

then

```
parent.filter(byId(1000))[0].child.filter(byId(2000))[0];
```

You can also define a more generic filter function:

```
by = function(key, value) { return function(item) { return item[key] == value} }

parent.filter(by('id', 1000))[0].child.filter(by('id', 2000))[0];
```

Comment: I wonder what topic starter means by "overkill". If he talks about performance then this solution will be even slower than nested for.

Comment: @AlexanderM by overkill I suppose I mean overhead and amount of code required to accomplish

Comment: @njzk2 I appreciate the answer, but I would go for a loop before attempting this.

Comment: @ggwarpig : I don't see the point of a loop when `filter` does just what you are looking for.

Comment: @njzk2 got your code working here http://jsfiddle.net/MBP3q/  but when I try to implement it in my code keep getting "uncaught typeerror "cannot read property 'filter' of undefined.  Does this mean it thinks filter is the name of the key?  Still playing with this...

Comment: @ggwarpig `filter` is a function of `Array` the error you mention seems to indicate that `parent` is not defined?